# Framework Not Linking in XCode 4.5

Tags: xcode, xcode4.5

I added the iAd framework to my app, which has two targets. I am able to compile and run one of my targets, but the other does not compile. (The code that doesn't compile in one case does compile in the other case.) Apparently, the framework is not recognized or linked.

I checked the linked libraries in Build Phases for both targets, and the framework is listed. Most of my other libraries were added before I split off another target, and I didn't have this problem for most of them. I recall having something like this happen once before, where I went back into build phases and removed and re-added the framework. That resolved the problem. (I don't remember exactly what I did that one time, though.) I tried this again, and it still does not work.

What can I look for to see what is happening and how I might fix it?

I'm compiling for a target with iOS 5.0 using SDK 6.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your iAD framework is set as a member for the second target.

In other words, look at the file inspector for your iAD framework and make certain the checkmark is checked for ***both*** targets.

Here is what it looks like just for a .m file... it would be the same case for the framework:

[image: make certain membership is checked]